# Split helm window in different directions

Tags: helm, window-splitting

I'd like `helm-buffers-list` to split my window horizontally, but I'd like for all other Helm functions to split it vertically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

See `helm-split-window-default-side` for this.

You can set this in your init file or via `M-x customize-variable`

It accepts args above, below, left, and right. Once you update and save, helm will appear wherever you've specified.

Comment: I want different splits for different helm functions.

Answer (score 2):

> I want different splits for different helm functions

You can create your own wrapper that binds `helm-split-window-default-side` to the value you want. E.g.

```el
(defun my-helm-buffers-list ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((helm-split-window-default-side 'left))
    (helm-buffers-list)))
```